# Magento 2 - Ajax call on controller working in desktop but not on mobile

Tags: magento2, ajax, jquery, mobile-device

Here is the ajax call in which data is not passed in controller
This is found only in mobile device and working fine in desktop.

Thanks in advance.

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '<?php echo $this->getUrl('sms/customer/register')?>',
                data:{'mobile':mobile},
                beforeSend: function()
                {
                    
                    Smsresetdata();
                    Smstoggeldata('#getotpbtn');
                    Smstoggeldata('#waitsmsdiv');
                },
                success: function(data)
                {
                    if(data == 'success')
                    {
                        Smstoggeldata('#waitsmsdiv');
                        Smstoggeldata('#otpdiv');
                        Smstoggeldata('#resendotpbtn');
                        $('#mobilenumber').attr('readonly', true);
                    }
                    else
                    {   
                        Smstoggeldata('#waitsmsdiv');
                        Smstoggeldata('#getotpbtn');
                        $('#smserror').html(data);
                    }
                },
                error: function(e) {
                    Smstoggeldata('#waitsmsdiv');
                    Smstoggeldata('#getotpbtn');
                $('#smserror').html('<?php echo __('Something went wrong, Try again later.') ?>');
                }
            });
```